# CakePHP v3.x how to bake without database connection

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake

I'm using CakePHP v3.x and my app doesn't have any models but I'd like to back a couple views or controllers.

`$ bin/cake bake template Reports`

I tried:
* using the `--connection` option with false or an empty string
* Removing `Datasources` from app.php
* Leaving in `Datasources` but set `Datasources['default']` to `false`

All of these result in an error:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v3.1.2 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/listings/src/
PHP : 5.6.10
---------------------------------------------------------------
Exception: The datasource configuration "default" was not found. in [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/listings/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Datasource/ConnectionManager.php, line 187]
2015-10-22 02:30:48 Error: [Cake\Datasource\Exception\MissingDatasourceConfigException] The datasource configuration "default" was not found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'name' => 'default',
)
Stack Trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/listings/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Locator/TableLocator.php(164): Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::get('default')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/listings/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/TableRegistry.php(109): Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator->get('Reports', Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/listings/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/TemplateTask.php(282): Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get('Reports')
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/listings/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/TemplateTask.php(147): Bake\Shell\Task\TemplateTask->_loadController()
#4 [internal function]: Bake\Shell\Task\TemplateTask->main('Reports')
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/listings/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/Shell.php(447): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/listings/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/Shell.php(442): Cake\Console\Shell->runCommand(Array, false)
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/listings/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(212): Cake\Console\Shell->runCommand(Array, true, Array)
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/listings/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(179): Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher->_dispatch(Array)
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/listings/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(126): Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher->dispatch(Array)
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/listings/bin/cake.php(33): Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#11 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this will work any time soon. You can create feature request type ticket on Github but it's unlikely to happen, because bake uses the DB schema to read the fields and builds everything based on the schema.

Also the Table class, which replaced Model from Cake2, doesn't allow `$useTable = false` any more. Because a table requires a DB table. For model less forms [see this link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just out of curiosity, does `bake` use the schema at all for templates or controllers?